# Интерфейс окна сообщений. Оптимальная архитектура

Tags: javascript, html

Требуется создать окно сообщении по типу аськи. Сообщения будут хранится в XML файле откуда будут выбираться и подгружаться.
Какие элементы для вывода элементов можете порекомендовать?

Я предполагал делать так :

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>привет</li>
    <li>приветик</li>
    <li>как дела?</li>
    <li>все хорошо. а ты как ?</li>
    <li>олично</li>
    <li>как погода?</li>
    <li>дождик</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

В div реализуется прокрутка и все такое. В список JS добавлять новые элементы. В li выставлять классами требуемую разметку (разбивка по цветам и выравнивание по правой левой стороне).
  Удобна ли такая реализация?  И какие могут быть подводные камни?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно делать как удобнее, но есть несколько "Плюсов" в выбранном вами способе.

- Чат - это список сообщений - вполне логично использовать семантически подходящие элементы такие как ul
- С помощью списков можно организовать ответы на сообщения (где ответ идет с отступом, т.е. многоуровневые списки
- Li - блочные элементы, поэтому проблем с вставкой в них других элементов возникнуть не должно
- Из сложностей: если вы захотите сделать многоуровневые ответы и при этом сделать ленивую загрузку старых сообщений (т.е. не показывать все сообщения за все время разом, а только при прокрутке к началу списка), то вам придется побеспокоится о иерархии списков сообщений

Тем не менее есть вариант сделать как в "вконтакте", т.е. на таблице. В этом есть смысл если вам хочется сообщения верстать в табличном стиле.

Лично мое мнение - для меседжера подходит больше UL-LI.

Comment: насколько я помню таблицы грузится полностью. если большой диалог то процесс загрузки на ленивых сетях может быть не очень красивым отображаться. а вот списки могут грузится частями.

Comment: Да вы правы, решением этого может быть разбивание таблицы на несколько (и грузить их можно тоже при необходимости) и **[table-layout: fixed](http://www.eriwen.com/css/use-the-table-layout-css-property-to-speed-up-table-rendering/)**.

Comment: Думаю UL-LI  будет достаточно. спс

Answer (score 1):

> Удобна ли такая реализация?

Для описанной задачи — нормально.

> И какие могут быть подводные камни?

Скорее всего, подводные камни появятся, когда вы захотите добавить к сообщениям отметки времени, отметки о прочтении, захотите как-то выделять непрочитанные сообщения и т.д. Всё зависит от того, что будет с программой дальше.

P.S. Вопросы, подобные этому, кажется, не очень конструктивны, т.к. на них нельзя дать однозначный ответ. Лучше начните делать чат и задавайте вопросы по конкретным проблемам, если, конечно, не найдёте ответов в google.

Comment: Отметки времени и другие сопутствующие элементы также можно добавлять в li.   
Насчет конструктивности вопроса, не соглашусь с вами. Выбор изначально удобной архитектуры снимает кучу проблем.